# How to get TextEditor From TextDocument

Tags: vscode-extensions

Currently I have a TextDocument from the event callback of onWillSaveTextDocument. I want to edit this text document, but to do so I need the class TextEditor. How would I get the associated TextEditor from this TextDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array `vscode.window.visibleTextEditors` and find the TextEditor through comparing the documents:

```js
const editor = vscode.window.visibleTextEditors.find(
   (editor) => editor.document === ev.document
);
```